# Propose new time Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I was going through the Microsoft Graph APIs and was unable to find an API to propose a new time for meetings. There seems to be methods for accept, decline and tentatively accept.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The propose new meeting API isn't yet exposed. Please upvote this feature request:
https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/17383252-expose-propose-new-meeting-time-api